# Convolution of two binomial distribution

Tags: mathematical-statistics, binomial-distribution, convolution

The problem and some of my thought are as followed, could you help check if I'm wrong.

Suppose $X∼Bin(n_1,1/2)$ and $Z∼Bin(n_2,p)$, $0<p<1$ being an unknown parameter; $X$ and $Z$ are assumed to be independent. Due to (spatial) aggregation, we can only observe $Y=X+Z$.

Is there always an MLE of $p$?

With the replicate of $Y$, and by the convolution formula of pdf,
$f_Y(y)=\sum_{x=0}^{n_1+n_2}f_X(x)f_Z(y-x)=\sum_{x=0}^{n_1}C_{n_1}^x(1/2)^{n_1}\times C_{n_2}^x p^x(1-p)^{n_2-x}$ something like this.
And then, we construct the likelihood function, find its argmax solve for p. I think it is kind of obvious, only the calculation is annoying.

But what does the question really mean? Is ther any case that a MLE will not exist?

And are there consistent estimators of p based on Y alone?

Comment: 1. Your convolution is wrong. You would need to take more care over it. 2. It might be worth actually trying a few small examples before trying to figure it out.  3. Also your use of the "C" notation for enumerating combinations is not standard (usually I'd see one of these notations .... $^n\!C_x =\: _n\!C_x = C^n_x = C_{n,x} = C(n,x) = {n\choose x} = \frac{n!}{x!(n-x)!}$ but yours is being used differently from those -- you seem to have $x$ and $n$ swapped around from what I'd expect; so you'd better define what you mean by your notation).

Answer (score 1):

Let's look at the likelihood function for small values of $n_1$ and $n_2$ (see the R code at the end):
[image]

This isn't a mathematical proof, but from these graphs we can fairly confidently conjecture that there is always a unique MLE except when

- $n_2=0$, or
- $n_2=1$ and $n_1$ is odd with $y=(n_1+1)/2$.

As for whether there is a consistent estimator of $p$ based on $Y$, the answer will depend on the asymptotics that you assume for $n_1$ and $n_2$. It should be intuitively obvious that if $n_2$ does not grow fast enough, relative to $n_1$, then the "noise" from $X$ will drown out the "signal" in $Z$, making consistent estimation impossible. But as long as $n_2$ does grow fast enough, relative to $n_1$, then consistent estimation will be possible.

To see how this works, instead of the MLE we can first look at a simpler, method-of-moments estimator. We have

$$E(Y) = E(X) + E(Z) = \frac{n_1}{2} + n_2p$$

So if we set
$$ \hat p = \frac{Y - \frac{n_1}2}{n_2}$$
then $\hat p$ is an unbiased estimator of $p$ (assuming $n_2>0$). We can then compute the variance
$$ \text{Var}(\hat p) = \frac{n_1}{4n_2^2} + \frac{p(1-p)}{n_2}$$
The variance then converges to zero as long as $n_2\to\infty$ and $n_1/n_2^2 \to 0$. In other words, $n_1$ must grow less quickly than $n_2^2$. Under these conditions, the method-of-moments estimator $\hat p$ is a consistent estimator of $p$, and so the MLE (being asymptotically optimal) must also be consistent under these same conditions.

**R code for generating the chart:**

```
library(tidyverse)

like_fun = Vectorize(function(n1, n2, y, p){
  z = 0:min(y,n2);
  sum(choose(n2,z)*p^z*(1-p)^(n2-z)*choose(n1,y-z)*2^(-n1))
})

df = expand.grid(n1 = 0:4, n2 = 0:4, y = 0:8, p = seq(0, 1, .01)) %>% 
  filter(y <= n1 + n2) %>%
  mutate(L = like_fun(n1, n2, y, p),
         n1 = paste("n1 = ", n1),
         n2 = paste("n2 = ", n2))

df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = p, y = L, color = factor(y))) +
  facet_grid(n2 ~ n1) +
  geom_line(aes(group = y)) +
  labs(x = 'p',
       y = 'Likelihood',
       color = 'y') +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90))
```